# Split NSArray into sub-arrays based on NSDictionary key values

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, filtering, split

We have an app that calls a SOAP web service and retrieves a long list of XML, which the app then parses into an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects. The `NSArray` contains a list of Rental Apartment information, each of which is stored into an `NSDictionary`.

The entire list may contain 10 different types of Apartments (i.e. 2-room, 3-room), and we need to split the `NSArray` into smaller `NSArray`s based on Room-Type, which has the key "roomType" in the `NSDictionary` objects.

Currently our algorithm is

1. Use `[NSArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionofObjects.room-type"]`
   to obtain a list of unique room-type values.
2. Loop through the list of unique room-type values
3. For each unique room-type value, use `NSPredicate` to retrieve matching items from the Original list

Our code is below (renamed for clarity):

```
NSArray *arrOriginal = ... ...; // Contains the Parsed XML list

NSMutableArray *marrApartmentsByRoomType = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

NSMutableArray *arrRoomTypes = [arrOriginal valueForKeyPath:@"distinctUnionOfObjects.roomType"];

for(NSString *strRoomType in arrRoomTypes) {
  NSPredicate *predicateRoomType = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"roomType=%@", strRoomType];

  NSArray *arrApartmentsThatMatchRoomType = [arrOriginal filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicateRoomType];  // TAKES A LONG TIME EACH LOOP-ROUND

  [marrApartmentsByRoomType addObject:arrApartmentsThatMatchRoomType];
}
```

However, step 3 is taking a long time as the original list may contain large amount (>100,000) of items. It seems that `NSPredicate` goes through the entire list for each key value. Is there a more efficient way of splitting a large `NSArray` into smaller `NSArray`s, based on `NSDictionary` keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the order of your splited Arrays is not important, i have a solution for you:

```
NSArray *arrOriginal;
NSMutableDictionary *grouped = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:arrOriginal.count];
for (NSDictionary *dict in arrOriginal) {
    id key = [dict valueForKey:@"roomType"];

    NSMutableArray *tmp = [grouped objectForKey:key];
    if (tmp == nil) {
        tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [grouped setObject:tmp forKey:key];
    }
    [tmp addObject:dict];
}
NSMutableArray *marrApartmentsByRoomType = [grouped allValues];
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Jonathan! Will try it out and test if the performance is better using this. It does seem that at minimum we have to loop through the entire original array once...

Answer (score 1):

This is quite performant

```
- (NSDictionary *)groupObjectsInArray:(NSArray *)array byKey:(id <NSCopying> (^)(id item))keyForItemBlock
{
    NSMutableDictionary *groupedItems = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    for (id item in array) {
        id <NSCopying> key = keyForItemBlock(item);
        NSParameterAssert(key);

        NSMutableArray *arrayForKey = groupedItems[key];
        if (arrayForKey == nil) {
            arrayForKey = [NSMutableArray new];
            groupedItems[key] = arrayForKey;
        }
        [arrayForKey addObject:item];
    }
    return groupedItems;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving @Jonathan answer

1. Converting array to dictionary
2. Maintaining the same order as it was in original array

   ```
   //only to a take unique keys. (key order should be maintained)
   NSMutableArray *aMutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

   NSMutableDictionary *dictFromArray = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

   for (NSDictionary *eachDict in arrOriginal) {
   //Collecting all unique key in order of initial array
   NSString *eachKey = [eachDict objectForKey:@"roomType"];
   if (![aMutableArray containsObject:eachKey]) {
       [aMutableArray addObject:eachKey];
   }

   NSMutableArray *tmp = [grouped objectForKey:key];
   tmp  = [dictFromArray objectForKey:eachKey];

   if (!tmp) {
       tmp = [NSMutableArray array];
       [dictFromArray setObject:tmp forKey:eachKey];
   }
   [tmp addObject:eachDict];

   }

   //NSLog(@"dictFromArray %@",dictFromArray);
   //NSLog(@"Unique Keys :: %@",aMutableArray);
   ```

   //**Converting from dictionary to array again**...

   ```
   self.finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   for (NSString *uniqueKey in aMutableArray) {
      NSDictionary *aUniqueKeyDict = @{@"groupKey":uniqueKey,@"featureValues":[dictFromArray objectForKey:uniqueKey]};
   [self.finalArray addObject:aUniqueKeyDict];
   }
   ```

Hope, It will help when client wants final array in same order as input array.