# Split a single NSMutableArray into two so that I can set each in each of the section in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I want to use multiple sections feature `UITableView`. I have a  single `NSMutableArray` which consists of data in dictionary format. In that dictionary there is a key which has values as '0' and '1'. 
I want to create two separate `NSMutableArray` out of that so that I can assign them accordingly in different sections.

For example :

```
if (indexPath.section==0) {

NSDictionary *Data = [roomList1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

} else {

NSDictionary *Data = [roomList2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

Comment: what is key of the value 0/1 in dictionary. You can use predicate to get different arrays of values with 0 and 1

Comment: can you show me some json data here?

Comment: LIST:( 
{
        d = "1";
        g = " Local";
        id = 9550;
        n = testapp1;
        s = available;
    },
        {
        
        d = "0"
        g = " Local";
        id = 5319;
        n = chatplus1;
        s = away;
    },

}    )

Comment: Need to split it based on that 'd' key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the value in your dictionary is always set you could do something like:

```
NSMutableArray *firstArray = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *secondArray = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSDictionary *dictionary in yourArray) {
        if ([dictionary objectForKey:@"yourValue"] isEqualToString: @"0") {
            [firstArray addObject:dictionary];
        } else if ([dictionary objectForKey:@"yourValue"]isEqualToString: @"1") {
             [secondArray addObject:dictionary];
        }
    }
```

Comment: then don´t cast it to an integer and use isEqualToString: @0" or @"1" check Madhumitha answer at least the comparing part ;)

Comment: I m a complete newbee in ios, can you explain me the "// add dictionary to first array data"

Comment: That was just a comment that should explain you what you need to do but i added my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
- (NSDictionary *)groupObjectsInArray:(NSArray *)array byKey:(id <NSCopying> (^)(id item))keyForItemBlock
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *groupedItems = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        for (id item in array) {
            id <NSCopying> key = keyForItemBlock(item);
            NSParameterAssert(key);

            NSMutableArray *arrayForKey = groupedItems[key];
            if (arrayForKey == nil) {
                arrayForKey = [NSMutableArray new];
                groupedItems[key] = arrayForKey;
            }
            [arrayForKey addObject:item];
        }

        return groupedItems;
    }
```

Ref: [Split NSArray into sub-arrays based on NSDictionary key values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335466/split-nsarray-into-sub-arrays-based-on-nsdictionary-key-values)

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
NSMutableArray * roomList1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray * roomList2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0;i< YourWholeArray.count;i++)
{
  if([[[YourWholeArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"YourKeyValueFor0or1"] isEqualToString "0"])
  { 
     [roomList1 addObject:[YourWholeArray objectAtIndex:i]];
  }
  else if([[YourWholeArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"YourKeyValueFor0or1"] isEqualToString "1"])
  {
     [roomList2 addObject:[YourWholeArray objectAtIndex:i]];
  }
}
```

Comment: i would use isEqualToString: when you compare strings.

Comment: But this is terminating the app with this error : *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x78e0b210'

Comment: This is the list I am getting on main NSMutabledictionary

LIST:( 
{
        d = "1";
        g = " Local";
        id = 9550;
        n = testapp1;
        s = available;
    },
        {
        
        d = "0"
        g = " Local";
        id = 5319;
        n = chatplus1;
        s = away;
    },

}    )

Comment: After processing this data using your provided snippet following is the error appearing in response :

2016-04-25 12:23:34.916 sampleproj[2519:39481] -[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b622000
2016-04-25 12:23:35.091 sampleproj[2519:39481] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b622000'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 0):

try this way :-

```
NSMutableArray *getdata=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
getdata=[results objectForKey:@"0"];

NSMutableArray *getdata2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
getdata2=[results objectForKey:@"1"];

use this two array and populate the section with now of rows at indexpathrow

define number of section 2

if (section==0){

getdata

}
else{

getdata2

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *roomList1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *roomList2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *key in [myDictionary allKeys]) {
    if (myDictionary[key] isEqualToString: @"0") {
        [roomList1 addObject: myDictionary[key]];
    } else {
        [roomList2 addObject: myDictionary[key]];
    }
}
```